# Nextjs application deployed on Cpanel

Tags: next.js, e-commerce, cpanel

I have deployed my ecommerce application which I used nextjs to build and deployed to cpanel. When you load up the website the css doesn't load up. But when you click on a product it will load up with the css the way it is supposed to and then once you click the home logo from the navbar the homepage will load up with the css. I have deployed the same exact application to vercel and there is no issue. I have followed the document on nextjs website to deploy on a custom server.  I even ran npm run build and uploaded it to cpanel but it still didn't work. [This is when you load up the site.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baPF4.png) [This is after you click on a product.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmcho.png) [This when you click the logo from the navbar to return to the homepage.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAUEx.png) [Server.js code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooZPo.png) [package.json code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Avttk.png) [cpanel setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FmnK.png) [File Setup.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYD3P.png)

I want the css to load up once the user opens the site.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.